# Use filter with angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-model

I use this code to add a property in the filter when a checkbox is cheked.

```
<input ng-model="filter['model']['first']" value="first" type="checkbox" name="model">
```

I tried to do this in the controller, to take the stateparams value and preselect the checkbox

```
$scope.filter = {};
$scope.model=$stateParams.model;
if($scope.model == 'first')
{filter="['model']['first']"}
else if if($scope.type == 'second')...
```

But it's not working, the filter is not working and I it don't match with any element anymore.

Comment: can't set a value with only one `$stateParam` for something that requires both a key and a value. Does `$stateParams` also have a property that includes a value for the `model`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant to have?

```
$scope.filter = {};
$scope.model=$stateParams.model;
if($scope.model == 'first')
{
    $scope.filter="['model']['first']"
}
else if($scope.type == 'second'){
    ...
}
```

If so your problem is this:

```
$scope.filter = {};
$scope.model=$stateParams.model;
if($scope.model == 'first')
{
    $scope.filter['model'] = {};
    $scope.filter['model']['first'] = ???;
}
else if($scope.type == 'second'){
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to set your `['model']['first']` too.

Comment: `$scope.filter="['model']['first']"` as a string makes no sense

Comment: I know, that's why my solution does not include it.